# Getting memory leak error from UseEffect for react native navigation auth flow

Tags: reactjs, react-native, memory-leaks, use-effect

I am trying to set react native navigation auth flow but I give an error like;

> > **Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in a useEffect cleanup function.**

Most likely the error is caused by the codes here. I fixed it before while getting a different error from here, but now it gives a memory leak error.

```
  React.useEffect(() => {
    // Fetch the token from storage then navigate to our appropriate place
    const bootstrapAsync = async () => {
      let userToken;
      try {
        userToken = await SecureStore.getItemAsync(LOGIN_KEY);
        // IF USER ALREADY LOGGED IN CREATE NEW TOKEN TO KEEP USER LOGGED IN
        if(userToken!==null){
          let email = await SecureStore.getItemAsync(USER_NAME)
          let loginPassword = await SecureStore.getItemAsync(USER_PASSWORD)
          authContext.signIn({email,loginPassword})
                      .then(res=> {
                           if(res.response.status ==401){
                              authContext.signOut()
                              }
                            console.log(res)
                      })
                      .catch(err=>{ console.log(err)})
        }
        console.log("userTokennn ", userToken )
      } catch (e) {
        // Restoring token failed
        console.log("boostrapError", e)
      }
      // After restoring token, we may need to validate it in production apps
      // This will switch to the App screen or Auth screen and this loading
      // screen will be unmounted and thrown away.
      dispatch({ type: 'RESTORE_TOKEN', token: userToken });
    };
     bootstrapAsync();
  }, []);
```

Also, I tried to use clean up function but it didn't work like this;

```
};
    return ()=> bootstrapAsync();
  }, []);
```

The rest of the codes are here;

```
const authContext = React.useMemo(
    () => ({
      signIn: async (data) => {
        // In a production app, we need to send some data (usually username, password) to server and get a token
        // We will also need to handle errors if sign in failed
        // After getting token, we need to persist the token using `SecureStore`
        // In the example, we'll use a dummy token
         //SEND LOGIN INFO TO SERVER
       return await postSignIn(data.email, data.loginPassword)
        .then(async(res)=>{
            token = res.data.token
            await SecureStore.setItemAsync(LOGIN_KEY, token);
            await SecureStore.setItemAsync(USER_NAME, data.email )
            await SecureStore.setItemAsync(USER_PASSWORD, data.loginPassword )
            dispatch({ type: 'SIGN_IN', token: token });
        })
        .catch((err)=>{ console.log("sign in error", err); return err})
      },
    
      signOut: () => dispatch({ type: 'SIGN_OUT' }),
      signUp: async (data) => {
        // In a production app, we need to send user data to server and get a token
        // We will also need to handle errors if sign up failed
        // After getting token, we need to persist the token using `SecureStore`
        // In the example, we'll use a dummy token

        dispatch({ type: 'SIGN_IN', token: 'dummy-auth-token' });
      },
    }),
    []
  
  );
```

Answer (score 0):

Due to the async nature of api calls, there are cases when they will complete after component has been unmounted, e.g. user visits a page, the data starts loading, but before it's finished loading, the user has navigated to another page.
There are a few solutions here.

1. You can keep track of the component being mounted on the state.

```
const [mounted, setMounted] = useState(true);

React.useEffect(() => {
  if (mounted) {
    bootstrapAsync();
  }

  return () => {
    setMounted(false);
  };
}, []);
```

2. Use smth like [useAsync](https://github.com/streamich/react-use/blob/master/docs/useAsync.md) from react-use library, which takes care of this.

Comment: Unfortunately, it didn't work but It give an error in the font hook like this:

Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in a useEffect cleanup function.
at node_modules/expo-font/build/FontHooks.js:26:33 in loadAsync.then$argument_0

I use expo font like this:

  let [loaded] = useFonts({
    Rakkas: require('./assets/fonts/Rakkas-Regular.ttf')
  })


Should I use useFont somewhere else?

Comment: I solved it. The problem was in Splash Screen because I forgot to define the custom font in Splash screen. Thanks for trying to help me